# Unable to create Joomla user account through CiviCRM profile

Tags: profile, joomla, registration, user-account

Running Joomla 3.5.1, CiviCRM 4.7.7 with the user registration profile set to require Joomla account creation, a new civiCRM user profile is created, but a Joomla user account isn't created. The user registration profile worked in the past, but I don't know exactly when it stopped working. Creating a Joomla user account with using the default Joomla registration form directly works. Any suggestions for resolving?

Comment: I am running into the same problem
Joomla 3.6.5 with CiviCRM 4.7.14
When I activate the option that users can create an account when registering for an event, right before being sent to the PayPal page to pay for the event, I run into the following error message: Fatal error: Call to a member function setFieldAttribute() on boolean in /.../public_html/components/com_users/models/registration.php on line 307 Users can register trough the normal login module, that works fine, just trough CiviCRM its not possible. Please, any help is really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This issue is coming in case of multilingual site.

To resolve this issue , go to Root/components/com_users/models/registration.php,near line no. 307 find below mentioned code

```
    if (JLanguageMultilang::isEnabled())
    {
        $form->setFieldAttribute('language', 'type', 'frontend_language', 'params');
    }

    if (empty($form))
    {
        return false;
    }
```

**Replace with**

`if (empty($form))
{
    return false;
}`

if (JLanguageMultilang::isEnabled())
{
     $form->setFieldAttribute('language', 'type', 'frontend_language', 'params');
}

Try this solution.

Comment: Thank you. This resolves my issue with CiviCRM registrations not resulting in a Joomla user registration. Is there a way to force an update so that those who registered via civiCRM while it wasn't working can be added as Joomla users?

Comment: @CSDweb Could you post the question in your comment as a new Question as per the StackExchange guidelines that require a single question / single answer approach? You can provide a link to this question in the new one if you think the context will help. We don't want this to become a forum.